# How to skip immediate previous view on back button Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am working on Ionic2.
I have few pages e.g.

P1 -> P2 -> P3 -> P4

When I press back button on P4 or use navCtrl.pop(), it goes to P3. But I want to goto P2 if some conditions are met. Is it possible in Ionic2 to skip immediate previous view.
I cant set P2 as root on P4 back button. It should be that P3 is removed from back history.

Comment: In the documentation you can call remove: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/                                    remove(startIndex, removeCount, opts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code within your component class

```
@ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e: UIEvent) => {
       if(condition)  //put your condition here
           this.navController.remove(2); //if you want to skip P3
       this.navController.pop();
   }
}
```